# How do you display the current device position in ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I would like to display the current device position at every frame.
I am very new to iOS app development so would appreciate a thorough instruction.
I would like to know how I can run some function every time there is an update to the frame.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdateFrame frame: ARFrame) {
    statusMessage.text = "Frame Updated"
}
```

This does not work because the ARSession does not go into 'didUpdateFrame' state.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have forgotten to set the delegate. Adopt the ARSessionDelegate in your ViewController. Then, in `viewWillAppear` set the delegate to yourself

```
 sceneView.session.delegate = self
```

The method updateFrame should now be executed.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    print("Frame Updated")
}
```

On the other hand, you could also use the SCNSceneRendererDelegate and the method `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)`to setup your view before animations/actions etc.

Comment: I did this and was able to get some reading, but the 4th column of the 4x4 matrix (position I am assuming) is [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)]. How to I get non-zero values in the position

Comment: The last column is used for translation. Those values belong to the identity matrix so you are currently not applying any translation (custom placing).The last value of the last column is the homogeneous coordinate and I don't think you might need to change that. You can read more here about it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565827/whats-the-purpose-of-magic-4-of-last-row-in-matrix-4x4-for-3d-graphics